# Iphone - device - linker error

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors, libpng

I have added libpng to my application. If I build for simulator, everything is OK. When I build application for device, I got linker error:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_png_init_filter_functions_neon", referenced from: _png_read_filter_row in libpng-arm7-release.a(pngrutil.o)
```

I have build libpng manually from source, same way for simulator and device (only with changed target of compilation). I have tried to find this problem, but noone seems to post anything about this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I "solved" this by replacing lines 117-121 in `libpng`'s `pngpriv.h`:

```
#  ifdef __ARM_NEON__
#     define PNG_ARM_NEON_OPT 2
#  else
#     define PNG_ARM_NEON_OPT 0
#  endif
```

by

```
#define PNG_ARM_NEON_OPT 0
```

This disables ARM's NEON optimizations, which seems to be the cause of the problem.

This is merely a workaround though, I didn't have time to investigate the real cause of the problem further.

Comment: You need compile *.c files from arm folder.

Comment: you can also just compile with preprocessor flag "PNG_ARM_NEON_OPT=0" so you don't have to modify libpng source

Comment: Do we need to compile *.c after doing change in .h, and how?

Comment: I have to face the same problem in 3.1.0 version. i am trying to find the file location. Kindly give guide line to find that path of the file.

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P not quite sure what you're talking about since there's no version 3.1.0 of libpng.

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P ... ok, but this question is about libpng. So not sure what you are expecting here :)

Comment: I try to find the libpng file in my project. but i cannot, so i asking about the libpng file path

Comment: `find /path/to/your/project -name 'pngpriv.h'`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to PSyton's comment, here is how we solved it.
Compile the `arm/*.c` files. This however does only work for Android. For iOS, we additionally had to create a new `pnglibconf.h` with the entries:

```
#undef PNG_ARM_NEON_API_SUPPORTED
#undef PNG_ARM_NEON_CHECK_SUPPORTED
#define PNG_ARM_NEON_OPT 0
```

Looking at the ARM defines in libpng, it seems like they are a bit buggy currently, as `PNG_ARM_NEON_API_SUPPORTED` should be sufficient to turn NEON compilation off.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar error on macOS.
After getting libpng from the source
https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/
and compiling with the PNG_ARM_NEON option off, the error disappeared.