# Error while compiling iOS app with openCV framework on real device

Tags: ios, opencv, compiler-errors

With latest open cv framework i am unable to compile code on IOS device. i am facing following error.

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "_png_init_filter_functions_neon", referenced from:
>         _png_read_filter_row in opencv2(pngrutil.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Same app is able to compile for simulator but not for ios devices. Can any one tell me why i am facing this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to know that simulator is the simulator, and the real device is different. Your error log clearly says that the library your are using is not compiled for the 64 bit devices.

Comment: I don't know where from you got `opencv`, but 64 bit is supported by default on the latest `opencv` framework, get it from  - http://opencv.org/downloads.html

Comment: @FahriAzimov thanks for the reply. I know about differences and error. Yes i download from same place. 3.0 is working fine but 3.1 have this problem.

Comment: Hi guy's  I also have the same problem opencv framwork version 3.1 not archiving app on other side we can debug and test on real device but not able to archive the app. does any one know what goes wrong or I'm I doing it wrong  ?

Comment: @RahulShirphule You have to download code for github and recompile it with enabling it for 64 bit devices. I have not tired by my self and also do not know why open CV developer have not did it yet.

Comment: @shahzaib: done and I still get this error ...

Comment: This is awesomely strange. Same here. Version 3.0 works but 3.1 does not.

Comment: @Goz did enable 64 bit arc before compiling in cmake file ? https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/platforms/ios/cmake/Modules/Platform/iOS.cmake#L89

Comment: @Goz Follow this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976893/how-to-compile-opencv-for-ios7-arm64. One more thing is that  OpenCV version 3.1 and 3.0 is same for IOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had fixed this problem.The core of this problem is that we recompile some content in libpng,maybe it exits in other ios framework.Then it makes a conflict.Opncv 3.1 has 3rdparty in it's code.What you should do is find the lines 117-121 in libpng's pngpriv.h.Then just follow [Iphone - device - linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089014/iphone-device-linker-error).

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this commit fixes the issue, while still keeping NEON support for iOS devices:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/262a52f3063c50fbb1236e2cba2bd3c68f9979bb

Essentially, the clause that appends `-DENABLE_NEON=ON` to the `cmake` line was only applying to architectures beginning with `"armv"` (note the "v"); the above commit changes `opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py` to allow the cmake command to work with `"arm64"` as well.

Before:

```
    if arch.startswith("armv"):
        cmakecmd.append("-DENABLE_NEON=ON")
```

After:

```
    if arch.startswith("armv") or arch.startswith("arm64"):
        cmakecmd.append("-DENABLE_NEON=ON")
```

---

Diagnostic process, since it might be useful:

Found this by starting a `script build.log` before invoking `python ../opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios` and digging through output; `arm_init.c` was not built for `arm64` (which is where `png_init_filter_functions_neon` was defined) but was for `armv7` and `armv7s`.  From there, looking through `3rdparty/libpng/CMakeLists.txt` pointed at `ENABLE_NEON` not being set.

Comment: does cherry picking this commit into 3.1 branch solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem as @shahzaib described. In simulator it works but in iPhone its not working and showing the same error.

Previously I manually added OpenCV 3.1 in my iOS project. Later I changed it and install the OpenCV library via cocoapod https://cocoapods.org/pods/OpenCV

And in cocoapod there is 3.1.0.1 version which fixed the issue.

```
  pod 'OpenCV', '~> 3.1.0.1'
```