# cannot build anymore(Xcode8.0 iOS10.0.2)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, renpy

I tried to build game which is created by *renpy (Ren'Py 6.99.11.1749)*. I succeeded building the game on iOS simulator (iPhone 6). But I tried to run on my device (iPhone 5s, iOS 10.0.2) and that build failed. *Xcode (Xcode 8.0)* complains that:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_png_init_filter_functions_neon", referenced from:
      _png_init_filter_functions in libpng.a(pngrutil.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Others had the same issue before. It seems that the cause is due to optimizations for ARM neon that are not supported. See, e.g., [this bug report](https://github.com/fakhirsh/FEngine/issues/44) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19089014/1314743).

One solutions (work around) [seems to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089014/iphone-device-linker-error#comment34408557_19153406) to define the preprocessor flag `PNG_ARM_NEON_OPT=0`.

Comment: I added `PNG_ARM_NEON_OPT=0` to Debug of Preprocessor Macros, and set build configuration Debug. but cannot build it and remain the error.